# Почему не подключается Swiper slider?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, swiper, слайдер

Хочу подключить Swiper slider через CDN. Соответственно что бы сделать слайдер.
Вот код HTML boody:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <!-- слайдер -->
        <div class="image-slider swiper-container">
            <!-- обязательная оболочка -->
            <div class="image-slider__wrapper swiper-wrapper">
                <!-- слайд слайдера -->
                <div class="image-slider__slide swiper-slide">
                    <div class="image-slider__image">
                        <img src="../image/DoomImage1.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-slider__slide swiper-slide">
                    <div class="image-slider__image">
                    <img src="../image/DoomImage2.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- подключение файла js и подключение swiper. -->
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

В head я подключил важный css файл Swiper:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Сам я в слайдах сделал картинки по 700px ширины и высоты.
В javascript пишу следующие:

```
// подключаю .image-slider к Swiper если не ошибаюсь. Что бы этот элемент стал слайдером
new Swiper('.image-slider');
```

Но в итоге у меня не чего не работает.
Вот что пишет в Console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined
at script.js:2:16

В чем может быть проблема? Может я как то не правильно подключаю его?
Вот ссылка на скачивание самого проекта: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Auhudg02Qrd__w
(Яндекс диск).
Прошу помочь, делаю все ради учение.

Comment: Свой скрипт расположить ниже скрипта слайдера

Comment: @АлександрСычёв если я вас правильно понял, то нет, все равно нечего не получается.

Comment: @АлександрСычёв а нет, все работает, так что спасибо вам большое! Просто нужно было отчистить кэш что бы заработал этот обновленный код.

Comment: Есть еще момент с производительностью [тут не плохо раскрывается смысл](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup). Ну и в вашем варианте, есть такое событие `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){})` - оно срабатывает, когда все элементы страницы подгружены

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно поменять местами подключение файла js и подключение swiper, js файл просто не видит swiper

Answer (score 0):

нужно сперва загрузить swiper slider а потом js вот так:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```